# How to render only visible nodes inside a ScrollPane?

Tags: performance, caching, javafx, scrollpane

I'm using JavaFX to show thousands of nodes inside a ScrollPane. It gets laggy on nodes more than about 50. I'm adding each node by pane.getChilderen.add(myNewNode); and then move them to a specific position on the pane. How to make a pane to only render visible items to optimize the performance? Thanks.

Comment: The functionality you're describing is that of a virtualized control, such as `ListView` and `TableView`, etc. The implementation of those is private API in JavaFX, so if they don't directly suit your needs, you'll need to implement it yourself (which is non-trivial). There's a third-party library called [Flowless](https://github.com/FXMisc/Flowless); it doesn't appear to be under active maintenance, but the source code might at least give you some ideas.

Comment: To build off of what James_D says, creating a virtualized control will probably require you to keep a _model_ of what's being displayed. If you look at controls such as `ListView` and `TableView` you'll see they keep the data in a list. Then the implementation reuses `Cell` instances; as you scroll it updates the items of appropriate cells (and the cell is responsible or changing its view). So if you "go virtual" then you won't be keeping a comprehensive collection of nodes but will instead be creating, adding, and removing nodes—based on the backing model—as the user scrolls around.